# Run a C++ project

Tags: c++

```
Born.cpp  
Born.h  
build  
dist  
doc_TP2.doxyfile  
Makefile  
nbproject  
PrincipalProgram.cpp  
validationFormat.cpp  
validationFormat.h
```

In a main repository, I have all the files and directories. I tried running `g++ PrincipalProgram.cpp`, but I got the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/cc63Jbm6.o: in function `main':
PrincipalProgram.cpp:(.text+0xaf): undefined reference to `util::validerPointCardinal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: PrincipalProgram.cpp:(.text+0x16f): undefined reference to `util::validerPointCardinal(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: PrincipalProgram.cpp:(.text+0x22c): undefined reference to `bornesQuebec::Borne::Borne(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, double, int, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: PrincipalProgram.cpp:(.text+0x245): undefined reference to `bornesQuebec::Borne::reqBorneFormate[abi:cxx11]() const'
/usr/bin/ld: PrincipalProgram.cpp:(.text+0x2f4): undefined reference to `bornesQuebec::Borne::asgNomTopographique(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
/usr/bin/ld: PrincipalProgram.cpp:(.text+0x338): undefined reference to `bornesQuebec::Borne::reqBorneFormate[abi:cxx11]() const'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am not very experienced with c++ yet. How can I run this project?

**EDIT**

If I try running `make`  in the repo, I got this:

```
"make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/Session_Hiver_2021/Correction_IFT_1003/TP2/PourCorrection/solutionTp2/Tp2'
"make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tp2
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/Session_Hiver_2021/Correction_IFT_1003/TP2/PourCorrection/solutionTp2/Tp2'
make[2]: 'dist/Debug/GNU-Linux/tp2' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/Session_Hiver_2021/Correction_IFT_1003/TP2/PourCorrection/solutionTp2/Tp2'
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/Session_Hiver_2021/Correction_IFT_1003/TP2/PourCorrection/solutionTp2/Tp2'
```

Comment: IF you want to build the application you need to build all the source files. Simplist way is `g++ Born.cpp  PrincipalProgram.cpp validationFormat.cpp` but you should really look up how to build and then combine object files.

Comment: Run the makefile with the command `make`.

Answer (score 1):

The project contains a makefile. You can use the command `make` in the terminal. Makefiles contain the necessary instructions to compile the complete project.

If that, for whatever reason, fails then there is probably documentation somehwhere that you should read.

Comment: I have modified the question. Can you take a loot at it?

Comment: See my last sentence again.